# Java SE 1.3, cant use generics. Is my solution for storing/retrieving a custom object ok?

Tags: java, casting, arraylist

I have a custom class called Log. I can't create an arraylist of logs because I can't use generics. So, I create a standard arraylist (type object) and commit all of my "logs" to it. Then, when iterating over the arraylist later I simply cast "outcoming" objects as logs. i.e.

```
Log log = (Log) it.next();
```

Im not sure if this will work... or even if it does if it's the best idea. Really appreciate any feedback!

Comment: If only a `Log` object was put in, then only a `Log` object can be returned. (And yes, this is how pre-generic Java worked. It's a shame that the target is 1.3 ..)

Comment: First of all, I feel for you (using Java 1.3).  Second of all, yes it will work, so long as the Object in the iterator contains `Log` object or an object that can be cast to `Log`.  It might be saver to use `Object` first and then use `instanceOf` to determine if it is safe to perform the cast, but otherwise it's fine.  Ah, brings back (bad) memories ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer you are very true its best practice and safer to check the object before typcast with the help of instanceOf method. user1436117 I think you should try to move jdk 5 or greater.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will work.

In order to be in the safer side you can check whether the object is of type `Log` using [instanceof](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0060__Operators/TheinstanceofKeyword.htm) operator.

Ex

```
Object obj = it.next();
if( obj instanceof Log){
    Log log = (Log) obj;
    // Do something
} else {
    //Log a warning or error message
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how that's safer - it should die horribly and fast. Like with a Cast exception. If you're gonna do something if it breaks, might as well use the exception handling for exceptional situations. I would *only* use an `instanceof` if it was by design that several different types of elements could be added ..